# Getting "Class 'GroceryCrud\Core\GroceryCrud' not found" at the installation of Grocery CRUD

Tags: codeigniter-4, grocery-crud

After installing Grocery CRUD Enterprise at my Codeigniter 4 project, I am getting the following error:

```
Class 'GroceryCrud\Core\GroceryCrud' not found
```

Am I missing something? I've followed the instructions of the [Installation guide](https://www.grocerycrud.com/docs/grocery-crud-enterprise-codeigniter-4) but there is nowhere showing how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common mistake when you install Grocery CRUD Enterprise **without** composer. Since the library is not loaded through PSR-4 that is used from composer, the library needs to be explicitly called through the function include.

More specifically if your Controller starts with those lines:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Config\Database as ConfigDatabase;
use Config\GroceryCrud as ConfigGroceryCrud;
use GroceryCrud\Core\GroceryCrud;
```

You should add the below include right after the line `namespace App\Controllers;`

```
 include(APPPATH . 'Libraries/GroceryCrudEnterprise/autoload.php');
```

So your new Controller will look like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

// This is required
include(APPPATH . 'Libraries/GroceryCrudEnterprise/autoload.php');

use Config\Database as ConfigDatabase;
use Config\GroceryCrud as ConfigGroceryCrud;
use GroceryCrud\Core\GroceryCrud;
```